# Mysql Multiple Joins Slow Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb, query-performance

I am working on a search app that queries a large amount of info (100M+ rows) with multiple filters that can be used and I am having trouble getting it to perform when multiple filters are combined. When I have three or more joins the query takes hours to finish. Is there any way to make multiple joins a lot faster or am I doing something wrong? The following SQL fiddle explains the predicament:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db1eab8/1

For reference the table structure and slow query is also below:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- MariaDB 10.1 Table structures (simplified names and columns for this case)
-- ----------------------------
-- Contains the main information rows - this normally has 100M+ rows
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- Other columns would normally be here but were removed to simplify this
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- Contains the text content for a - This has the same amount of rows as `a`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a_content`;
CREATE TABLE `a_content` (
  `id_a` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_a`),
  FULLTEXT `f` (`title`,`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Contains whether an `a` ID is hidden for a user ID - This normally has 30M+ rows
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a_hidden`;
CREATE TABLE `a_hidden` (
  `id_a` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_a`,`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Contains an `a`'s country ID's - This normally has 300M+ rows
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a_country`;
CREATE TABLE `a_country` (
  `id_a` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_a`,`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- ----------------------------
-- Sample Records of a
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('3');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('4');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('5');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('6');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('7');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('8');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('9');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('10');

INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('1','aa sadd','aa');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('2','aasdadd sads','aa');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('3','aa daa','aaf df');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('4','aa sad','aadf ');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('5','aa v','aaxcv');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('6','aa c','aavv');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('7','aa df','aaaa');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('8','aa df','aa s');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('9','aa vvv','a a');
INSERT INTO `a_content` VALUES ('10','ss','aaaa');

INSERT INTO `a_hidden` VALUES ('1','1');
INSERT INTO `a_hidden` VALUES ('3','1');
INSERT INTO `a_hidden` VALUES ('5','1');
INSERT INTO `a_hidden` VALUES ('7','1');
INSERT INTO `a_hidden` VALUES ('9','1');

INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('1',1);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('1',2);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('2',1);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('3',2);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('4',4);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('5',112);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('6',33);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('7',44);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('8',66);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('9',88);
INSERT INTO `a_country` VALUES ('10',99);
```

Query:

```
# Extremely slow and takes hours even though it's using indexes all over. If I remove one join it's instantly fast though
SELECT a.id
FROM  `a` 
LEFT JOIN a_hidden ON a_hidden.id_a = a.id && a_hidden.user=1
LEFT JOIN a_content ON a_content.id_a = a.id
INNER JOIN a_country ON a_country.id_a = a.id && a_country.country IN (1,2,3) 
WHERE a_hidden.id_a IS NULL && MATCH (a_content.title, a_content.description) AGAINST ('search' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY a.id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 50
```

The Explain of the above query and table structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `LEFT JOIN` is in the way -- it prevents starting with the `MATCH`, which would be optimal.
- `is_hidden` complicates indexing; either remove such rows from the tables, or filter afterwards.
- Since `a.id` is everywhere, and it is the only selected column, this can't be a realistic query.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the other fields that are selected are all from the a table which did not affect performance of this large query by much when I removed it and just used a.id. I kept it removed here for simplicity sakes. is_hidden is mapped to certain users so I can't remove the rows from the table because that would remove it for all users. Is there a better way to do what I am doing apart from having to use a search engine which is what I had to do because I found no other option?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. MySQL doesn't work well as a search engine. I went with a search engine and selects with multiple filters are instant.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting **&& a_hidden.user=1**  and **&& a_country.country IN (1,2,3)** in **WHERE** clause. Don't add conditions in join keep conditions in **WHERE** Clause.

Comment: `&& a_hidden.user=1` is part of a non-exists clause. You cannot put that in a WHERE clause without changing the logic of the query.

Answer (score -1):

I'm moving from a SQL Server Express to a MySql Database And found some queries with performance bottleneck.

I've managed to it using a pattern "Column Not In (Select ...)" from old Sybase Databases and MySql Works well in some cases.